# Doesn't backface culling make it run faster? Should it not be on for most objects?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Doesn't backface culling make it run faster? Should it not be on for most objects?
It seems like the times you want to see tris from both sides are the exception, not the common case.
It won't make a difference for Cycles, but I assume Evee and all preview modes run faster.
I assume backface culling is off by default so people don't need to turn it off every time they need it, but could there be more reasons to leave it off I don't know?